# programa en c q abra un archivo word q ya existe

Tags: c, ms-word

hola buenos he estado buscando alguna forma para lograr hacer un programa en lenguaje "c" que me habrá un word  de mi ordenador sin la necesidad de pinchar sobre este encontré esto pero no me funciona.

## include

int main(){

system("openword"); //Asi se abre

return 0;

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al igual como abres cualquier programa por consola. Debes poner la dirección del archivo completa ejm "C:\Users\cmanz\OneDrive\Documentos\Word\Tarea5.docx". si quieres abrir el word como vacio, debes ir donde lo tienes instalado.

ahora vamos al codigo: la estructura de system() requiere al comienzo un "\" seguido por la direccion del archivo o programa "C:\Users\cmanz\OneDrive\Documentos\Word\Tarea5.docx" teniendo asi

```
int main()
{
system( "\""C:\\Users\\cmanz\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Word\\Tarea5.docx"" );
return 0; 
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178944/how-to-execute-an-external-program-in-c

Comment: vale gracias pero yo se lo tengo q entregar a mi profesor entonces no habria alguna forma de abrirlo sin saber en que carpeta lo ha guardado>>?

Comment: scanf(); y que el entregue toda la url.